# Service not found a repository bean in my Springboot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

First of all, I want to give many thanks to everyone who read my question and want to help me solve it so, I have a problem which about not found bean in my project. I have a repository named "UserRepository" and in my service is "UserService" has @Autowired that repository, its not found my repository although I added repository annotation. "UserService" not found the repository bean

This is my problem:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.baothien.server.User.UserService required a bean of type 'com.baothien.server.User.UserRepository' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.baothien.server.User.UserRepository' in your configuration.
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

My Project Structure:
[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTVxz.png)

UserRepository.java

```
package com.baothien.server.User;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Users")
    List<User> getAllUsers();
}
```

UserService.java

```
package com.baothien.server.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
package com.baothien.server.User;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private final UserService userService;
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "GET User API succesfully!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/get-users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }
}
```

User.java

```
package com.baothien.server.User;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Entity
@Table
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "user_sequence",
            sequenceName = "user_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "user_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String fullName;
    private String role;
    private String password;
}
```

Main method

```
package com.baothien.server;

import com.baothien.server.User.UserController;
import com.baothien.server.User.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.baothien.server.User.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.baothien.server.User.*"})
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried my best but this problem was not solved, I really need a solution.
Thanks for reading my question, see you.

**UPDATE**: I use @ComponentScan:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.baothien.server.User.*")
```

It run but when I test on Postman, it has White Label Error, not found page (http://localhost:8080/api/v1/test). As you see, my controller has /test path, I don't understand why it have this error.

I tried find the solution on many forum but cannot solve that problem

Comment: Remove `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`. Remove `@Repository` from your interface and ditch the `getAllUsers`, Spring Data already provides the `findAll` method for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hard.

1. You don't need `@EntityScan`
2. You don't need `@EnableJpaRepositories`
3. `@Repository` on a Spring Data repository interface doesn't do anything
4. `JpaRepository` or rather `CrudRepository` already has a `findAll` to retrieve all entities. Ditch your `getAllUsers` method.
5. You are using the wrong `@Id` you are using the Spring Data one whereas you need the `jakarta.persistence` one.

Point 4 and 5 are actually your issues as the query you have written is wrong it should read `SELECT u FROM User u`. It is a JPQL and not a SQL query. However as stated you don't need it as there is already a `findAll` method. An `@Id` for JPA entities is required, so that makes it fail as well.

Comment: Problem is solved, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your basePackages is too narrow. Try

```
EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.baothien.server"})
```

Comment: Entity 'com.baothien.server.User.User' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)

Not found @Entity

Comment: You might be most likely facing issue because the user is keyword in most of the databases and you cannot create a table with name of user. You have 2 options here, Option 1) rename your entity class to Users or something more meaningful. Option 2) you can include the name attribute to your table annotation in the entity class with meaningful name. Something like `@Table(name = "Users")`.